# dos batch: convert time to frames (floating-point arithmetic)

Tags: windows, batch-file, audio, dos

in a variable %waveDuration% I have time duration in this notation 0:00:35.368667 (0 hours, 0 minutes, 35 sec + various millisec)

I would like convert it in number of frames @ 25 fps PAL

so that 35.36 X 25 = 884,21 --> rounded = 884 (result to be put in a new variable %framecount%)

I have try 2 type of batch calcultator but I'm wrong in something that I cannot resolve. Please how I can do? thanks

```
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=:," %%a in (
        "%waveduration%"      
    ) do set /a "framecount"=((%%a00)*3600 + (%%b00)*60 + (%%c00) + (%%d0)/10 ) * 25 / 100
```

and putting the value in a .txt

```
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=:," %%a in ('c:\duration.txt') do set /a "number_Of_Frames=((%%a00)*3600 + (%%b00)*60 + (%%c00) + (%%d0)/10 ) * 25 / 100"
```

but, as sayd: this seems don't work

Comment: "it doesn't work"... what does it do? how is it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```dos
set "t=:%waveduration:.=:%"
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=:" %%a in ("%t::0=: %") do set /a "framecount=((%%a00)*3600 + (%%b00)*60 + (%%c00) + (%%d0)/100000 ) * 25 / 100"
echo %framecount%
```

With everything converted to hundredths of a second to operate.

**edited**: as indicated by mojo, this solucion is tightly asociated to the milliseconds format, that also need a different way to handle them (in this case the leading zeroes are significant). If it can vary, then

```dos
set "waveduration=0:00:35.368667"

for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=:." %%a in (":%waveduration::0=: %") do (
    set "framecount=1%%d00" 
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for /f %%x in ("!framecount:~0,3!") do ( 
        endlocal 
        set /a "framecount=((%%a00)*3600 + (%%b00)*60 + (%%c00) + (%%x-100) ) * 25 / 100"
    )
)
echo %framecount%
```

Comment: Short and sweet. The only thing this doesn't handle are decimals with fewer than six digits. I don't know if that's a concern for the OP, though, depending on the source of the timestamp.

Comment: @mojo, sorry, this was a fast answer, directly written and without tests. Of course, you are right. The tailing digits can be a problem, but also leading zeroes that has to be taken into consideration. Answer updated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

CMD/Batch only really does integer arithmetic. You'd have to do the floating point stuff all by yourself. In this example, I'm treating the fractional seconds as an integer, multiplying by the frame rate first, then dividing by the deduced fractional denominator (10<sup>num_digits</sup>).
I also had to perform successive `SET /A` operations because CMD didn't like expressions that included parentheses.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "waveduration=0:00:35.368667"

SET FRAME_RATE=25
FOR /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:." %%a IN ("%waveduration::0=:%") DO (
    SET DENOM=1
    FOR /L %%i IN (0,1,8) DO (
        IF %%d GTR !DENOM! SET /A DENOM*=10
    )
    SET /A "framecount=(%%a*3600 + %%b*60 + %%c)*%FRAME_RATE% + %%d*%FRAME_RATE%/!DENOM!"
)
@ECHO %waveduration% : %framecount%
```

Comment: This will not work with a Wave duration of :0:09:35.368667 (for eaxample) the 09 will be treated as octal value and will  give a fatal error.

Comment: @SachaDee Correct. I've modified to fix the radix problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using Powershell in your bat script :

```
@echo off
SET "waveduration=0:05:35.368667"
for /f  "tokens=1-4 delims=:."  %%a in ('echo %waveduration%') do (
  for /f "delims=" %%x in ('powershell ^(0.%%d + ^(%%a * 3600^) + ^(%%b * 60^) + %%c^)*25') do echo FrameCount = %%x)
```

Comment: Thanks Sacha, only one thing: I have try it using for example 0:00:35.368667 but I get 1105,416875 frames instead of 884,21. Please how can it be correct? thanks!

Comment: Corrected a small bug.